# How to filter out text that contains one or more of the following words

Tags: angularjs, filter

If I had an array of objects

```
var obj = [{
  text: "Hello my name is none of your business"
  },
  { 
  text: "This is the second text of this object, hello"
  },
  { 
  text: "This is the third text of this object, hello"
  },{ 
  text: "This is a copy of the third text of this object, hello"
  }];
```

How could I filter out all objects that contain keywords not necessarily in order? An jsfiddle is provided for further clarification

e.g.

- user searches "this", filter returns second,third, and fourth text
- user searches "third copy", filter returns just the fourth text,

The problem is that using the basic filter (an example below) seems to search for exact phrases. e.g. "third copy" will return an empty result. The user has to type in "copy of the third" to get a result back.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpm2uamf/

I was think of using the split function on all single whitespace and then somehow loop through that using Regex...but I clearly have no idea what I'm doing

```
.filter('searchBody', function(){
return function(elements, input){


  if(input !== undefined){
    var inputs = input.split(" ");

  }
  var filtered = [];
  // loop through user inputs and make them optional in RegExp?
  var letterMatch = new RegExp(inputs, 'i');
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var element = elements[i];
    if( letterMatch.test(element.body)){
      filtered.push(element);
    }
  }
  return filtered;
};
})
```

Could someone give me hints or an explanation of how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a custom filter that does that:

```
app.filter('multipleTags', function($filter) {
  return function multipleTags(items, predicates) {
    predicates = predicates.split(',')

    angular.forEach(predicates, function(predicate) {
      items = $filter('filter')(items, predicate.trim())
    })
    return items;
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZhnuM0WW3GZS5QLxK98t?p=preview

although my code was designed for comma separated tags it can be reused for spaces in your case

Comment: Wow this is perfect, thanks a lot! You've definitely saved me from a lot of pain. If I had at least 15 rep I would upvote ha. But I'm definitely choosing this as an answer once I'm allowed. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I'd been looking for this for a day or two. Great filter.  Solved 9 problems all at once for me.  Thank you.